# Kendo UI Angular Grid - Collapse all headers

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo grid based on the following structure:

```
    Master Group A
        Sub Group A
            -Data A-
            -Data B-
        Sub Group B
            -Data C-
            -Data D-
        Sub Group C
            -Data E-
            -Data F-
    Master Group B
        Sub Group A
            -Data G-
            -Data H-
        Sub Group B
            -Data I-
            -Data J-
        Sub Group C
            -Data K-
            -Data L-
    Master Group C
        Sub Group A
            -Data M-
            -Data N-
        Sub Group B
            -Data O-
            -Data P-
        Sub Group C
            -Data Q-
            -Data R-
```

I'm wanting it to look something like the following when the page first loads up:

```
    Master Group A
        Sub Group A
        Sub Group B
        Sub Group C
    Master Group B
        Sub Group A
        Sub Group B
        Sub Group C
    Master Group C
        Sub Group A
        Sub Group B
        Sub Group C
```

My data currently is one data part per line. Each line of data is it's own data.
Does anyone know how to do this?

- I have a Kendo Angular2 Slack: https://kendouiangular2.slack.com

Comment: You could make a main grid with your 1st and 2nd level groups, and use a template with another grid inside for your data. You will be able to expand/collapse the sub grids with +/- button. See http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/configuration/#toc-the-detail-template

Comment: Thats not what i asked for though. All the data within the group is on one line and there can be multiple lines

Comment: So what is it you want exactly? To be able to hide/display your data in each group? Do your data lines have the same columns as your sub groups lines?

Comment: Yes. Each data line has 5 columns with data in each, matching the column headers

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution in Kendo grid for angular2 for doing that.

I can think of 2 approaches :

1) Filtered array of data

You could have 2 arrays of data : one reference/readonly array with all groups, subgroups and data, and a filtered array dedicated to display, where you add/remove data in each subgroup when you click on a button in your subgroup line.

Then you bind your grid data to the filtered array, and modify the filtered array on events on your sub-group buttons.

2) CSS-only

Single array of data, and then apply classes to the `<tr>` tags of the kendo grid to show/hide your data lines based on events on your sub-group buttons.
If you have jQuery on your project you can access those tr tags relatively easily with something like that:

```
$('.some-class-i-add-to-all-my-data-lines').parents('.k-master-row')
```

If you don't have jQuery it's a bit less straightforward.

Comment: I'd rather not have duplicate data and I don't use any `<tr>` tags

Comment: duplicate data is the most 'angular2-compliant' way. about tr tags, I'm talking about those which are generated by Kendo. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm using angular2, not angular and jQuery

Comment: Well then try solution 1), or get rid of Kendo grid and create a custom grid component of your own that you can customize as you'd like. There's no easy way of doing what ou want with Kendo for angular. edit: at least with the current version of kendo-angular-grid

Comment: I'm not sure about having 2 sets of the same data. Thanks for the reply anyway